# Excel - How to fill in empty lines below with current value until new value is met in the same column. Non-VBA solution needed

Tags: excel

I have several sheets with test cases. Currently they look like this:

```
    A | B | C..
------|---|---
TC-01 |MED|
      |   |
TC-02 |Hi-|
      |   |
      |   |
TC-03 |Low|
      |   |
```

I need the table to look like this:

```
    A | B | C..
------|---|---
TC-01 |MED|
TC-01 |   |
TC-02 |Hi-|
TC-02 |   |
TC-02 |   |
TC-03 |Low|
TC-03 |   |
```

...where every line in column **A** would autofill until the next value in the line below, and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: I thing this has to be done using macros

Comment: @Scott Craner - Not sure its duplicate of that question as I did not ask for VBA solution nor I put VBA tags. It would be nice to have non-VBA question and solution as separate entity.

Comment: @pnut have posted an easy solution. Quoting : "For those not requiring VBA for this, select ColumnA, Go To Special (press F5 and hit "Special" button).., Blanks and =, Up and Ctrl+Enter should give the same result."

Comment: As @Siva stated there is no non vba method beside that given by pnut or manually going into each cell and putting an individual formula to do this in place like you asked.  If you want it not in place then there would be a formula solution.  As it was you did not specify a formula solution, just a solution.  The linked question had both vba and non vba methods to answer your question, so it would be a duplicate as any answer would follow one of the three answers given.